# "Inject" a WHERE clause in an IQueryable before it performs a GROUP BY

Tags: linq

I have two tables: `Foo` and `Bar` that participate in a 1:M relationship, that is, each `Foo` has many related `Bar` instances.

I have a query like this:

```
IQueryable< IGrouping< Foo, Bar > > GetGroups() {

    return this.dbContext
        .Bar
        .Include( bar => bar.Foo )
        .GroupBy( bar => bar.Foo );
}
```

The consumer of `GetGroups` can then apply predicates that apply to each group, such as to filter on properties of `Foo` (which is the group key):

```
IQueryable< IGrouping< Foo, Bar > > query = GetGroups();

query = query.Where( grp => grp.Key.SomeFooProperty == "abc" );
query = query.OrderByDescending( grp => grp.Key.FooCreatedDate );
```

However, what if the consumer of `GetGroups` wants to apply a predicate to the `Bar` rows that are returned?

The straightforward solution is to supply it as a parameter of `GetGroups`:

```
    IQueryable< IGrouping< Foo, Bar > > GetGroups( Func<Bar,Boolean> barPredicate ) {

    return this.dbContext
        .Bar
        .Include( bar => bar.Foo )
        .Where( barPredicate )
        .GroupBy( bar => bar.Foo );
}
```

However this is not an option in my case.

Another option is to do a `SelectMany` and then manually regroup, but that seems ugly and I'm certain that would generate suboptimal SQL:

```
IQueryable<Bar> barsQuery = query.SelectMany( grp => grp );
barsQuery = barsQuery.Where( barPredicate );
query = barsQuery.GroupBy( bar => bar.Foo );
```

Is there a way to inspect an `IQueryable` and "inject" my `Where` clause in-between the `Include` the `GroupBy` statements?

Comment: Can you tell why *straightforward  solution* is not option in your case? I don't know your situation, but may be it will be better to try to find way of making it *an option* instead of trying to inject `where` clause. Probably there is some way of injecting it, but I can't think of any.

Comment: @AdilMammadov `GetGroups` is in a library I don't have access to. All I have is an `IQueryable`.